# easy way to do active link toggle

Tags: javascript

Hi I am building a page and I have an iframe which is pulling content and I would like my active links to appear to be active.

I have put together a JSFiddle of a super basic break down of what I am trying to accomplish.  Basically what I want to happen is when you click on one of the anchor tags it applies it's hover state.  And when you click another it removes that hover state and puts it back to original.  Thing is there are 3 different divs that I want to all toggle each other.

Help is greatly appreciated.  http://jsfiddle.net/u3p3C/1/

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/u3p3C/3/